# delete function not working but redirects to 404 page

Tags: php, codeigniter

### controller

```
public function delete_data(){
    $this->load->model('test_model');

    $data['query']=$this->test_model->delete_data($id);

    $this->index();
}
```

### model

```
public function delete_data($id)
    {
        $this->uri->segment(3);
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        return $this->db->delete('test'); 
    }
```

### view part

```
<a href="<?php echo site_url('test/delete_data/'. $row->id.'');?>">delete</a>
<a href="<?php echo site_url('test/edit_data/'. $row->id.'');?>">edit</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass $id variable in delete_data() method in controller too.
So method looks like:

```
public function delete_data($id){
    $this->load->model('test_model');

    $data['query']=$this->test_model->delete_data($id);

    $this->index();
}
```

There is no defined variable $id within method's  scope, router passes it as argument, but you need to pass it to method.